# JPA Embeddables, why does hibernate docs show as static classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on my first hibernate project, and am creating an `@Embeddable` class.

The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables) shows all the examples in that section (`@Embeddable` and `@Entity` classes) as static classes. What is the reason for that?

According to this snippet:

> Most often, embeddable types are used to group multiple basic type mappings and reuse them across several entities.

Since static classes can only be nested, and since many of the examples of `@Embeddables` I've seen here are not static, do you know why the docs were written that way?

Answer (score 0):

Static classes in docu could be part of some enclosing class.